# Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured. SpringBoot parent 3.1.2

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-jdbc, mysql-connector, spring-initializr

I got this problem when debugging.

```
2023-07-24T11:39:01.002+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] i.securecapita.SecurecapitaApplication   : Starting SecurecapitaApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 18324 (C:\Users\v.buithicam\Vb-Training\securecapita\securecapita\target\classes started by V.BUITHICAM in C:\Users\v.buithicam\Vb-Training\securecapita)
2023-07-24T11:39:01.012+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] i.securecapita.SecurecapitaApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-24T11:39:03.109+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-07-24T11:39:03.193+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-24T11:39:03.390+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 82 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2023-07-24T11:39:03.506+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-07-24T11:39:03.546+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-24T11:39:03.606+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-07-24T11:39:06.642+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-07-24T11:39:06.671+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-24T11:39:06.672+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2023-07-24T11:39:07.125+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-24T11:39:07.131+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5890 ms
2023-07-24T11:39:07.396+07:00  WARN 18324 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-07-24T11:39:07.486+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-07-24T11:39:07.780+07:00  INFO 18324 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-07-24T11:39:07.900+07:00 ERROR 18324 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I am trying start my project and check for connection with MySQL.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.</groupId>
    <artifactId>securecapita</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>securecapita</name>
    <description>Application to manage invoices and </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
                    <version>6.1.4.Final</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
                      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
                      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> 
                      <version>5.3.7.Final</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/securecapita
    password: YES
    username: root
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL8InnoDBDialect
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        globally-quoted-identifiers: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL8InnoDBDialect
        format_sql: true
  sql:
    init:
      mode: never
```

Comment: Remove the `org.hibernate` dependencies, those aren't needed (already part of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and you are mixing incompatible versions). Which will probably fail on the dialect (change it to `MySQL8Dialect` instead (and use either `database-platform` or the `dialect` they both set the same property in the end). Although it shouldn't be needed try to specify the `driver-class-name` property with the MySQL driver name.